Knex js Making a helper function to get a table's query builder
I'm trying to make my knex code simpler by removing knex.from('table') or knex('table') from my queries to something like table.where(...).select() and by doing this I make sure I'm not pointing to a wrong table or a typo.
And part of my solution is adding some code like this on my db.js file:
export const users = knex('users');
export const roles = knex('roles');

and then importing on any controller file like this example:
import { users } from "../lib/db.js";

const getUsers = async () => {
   return users.select();
}

But in older projects I had the issue that if I make multiple calls with the same query builder it won't make new query but instead adding logic to the first query.
Is there a way of doing this?

I believe you simply have to invoke it by awaiting its result.
import { users } from '../lib/db.js';

const getUsers = async () => {
   const users = await users.select();
   const someUser = await users.select().where({ name: someUser });

   return { users, someUser };
}

